# OSGi: missing package javax.security.auth on Java 8

Tags: java, macos, osgi, maven-3, netbeans-8

I've started developing an OSGI application on Mac OS X El Capitan using Maven 3.3.3 and NetBeans 8.1. At the moment the app consists of two minimal OSGI bundles.

If the compilation options are set to JDK 1.7, the application compiles and runs OK. However, with JDK 1.8, when the application is run, a message is generated complaining about the absence of java.security.auth even though it included in the JDK:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleEx: Unresolved constraint in bundle net.winnall.categories.Core [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] osgi.wiring.ception: Unresolved constraint in bundle net.winnall.categories.Core [5]: Unable to resolve 5.0: missing requirement [5.0] osgi.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.thoughtworks.xstream)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resolve 2.0:wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.thoughtworks.xstream)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) [caused by: Unable to resol missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.security.auth)])
ve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=javax.security.auth)]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1191)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:295)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I’m guessing that there is something OSGI-friendly in the 1.7 environment that is missing in 1.8.

The version info for 1.7 is

```
java version "1.7.0_04-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-ea-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b15, mixed mode)
```

and for 1.8 is

```
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

I’m using org.osgi.core-4.3.1.jar. I’ve tried using versions 5.0.0 and 6.0.0 without any change of behaviour.

Can anyone help me please?

Regards,
Steve

Comment: Have your tried a never build of Java 8? Yours is version "0" (and the Java 7 even an early access build)

Comment: @zapi I think the JDK is the latest version on Mac OS X. I hadn't noticed that the 1.7 was auncient. I've replaced it with 1.7.0_72, which also works correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of Felix are you running?

I have just tested a recent version of Felix running on Java 8, and the package `javax.security.auth` is exported by the system bundle, meaning it would be available to your application bundles.

But if your version of Felix is old, then it might predate Java 8 and lack a definition for the available JRE packages on that platform.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I created the OSGI bundle with NetBeans, which produced a Maven `pom.xml` in which the Felix version `4.0.3` was used. It never occurred to me to look at that more closely. After I changed these to the latest `5.4.0` it all worked.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the package "javax.security.auth". This package is probably part of the jre.

The OSGi framework typically has a list of configs called system package exports. These are the packages that the framework exports from the jre into OSGi. For each jre major version this list is different. So probably the system package exports for jre 8 do not list this package.

You have two options then. Either you export the package by defining a [framework property org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-configuration-properties.html). Or you install a bundle that contains and exports this package.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand you, but I can't make it work. I've created a file called `Felix.properties`, which appears in the JAR in `org.apache.felix.framework`. It contains `org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javax.security.auth;version=0.0.0`, where I chose 0.0.0 because I have no idea what the version number really is. Am I on the right track?